# Change the dimension of slices of a matrix, without wasting memory

Tags: r, memory, dimensions

I have a numeric matrix of considerable size (say gigabytes). I need to do some computations on this matrix by treating it as-is (a matrix), and some other computations where I need to treat slices of it as arrays of, say, two or three dimensions (the new dimensionality can be different from slice to slice).

My question is how I can do these two kinds of operation using as little memory as possible.

Here is an example with my tentative solution. I'm just using a 2×9 matrix as a manageable example:

```
m <- matrix(sample(18,2*(1+2*2+2*2)),nrow=2,ncol=1+2*2+2*2)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
## [1,]    3   10   12    2    7   15    6    1    9
## [2,]    8    4   18   17   13   14   11   16    5

#### I need to use m as-is in some function from some package
## some_result <- function_from_some_package(m)

#### Now I need to treat row 1, columns 2--5 as a 2*2 matrix,
#### let's say this represents some means.
#### And the same for row 1, columns 6--9,
#### let's say this represents some sds.
#### From these I want to calculate a matrix of normal density values:

somedata <- matrix(1:4, ncol=2) # these come from somewhere else

values <- dnorm(somedata, mean=matrix(m[1,2:5],nrow=2,ncol=2), sd=matrix(m[1,6:9],nrow=2,ncol=2))
##            [,1]      [,2]
## [1,] 0.01978261 0.0242596
## [2,] 0.00951157 0.0303845
```

The idea of using `matrix` (or `array` for more than two dimensions) to change the dimensionality of the needed slices of `m` comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14614946/6090141). My worry, however, is whether R is then internally creating two new objects, one for
`matrix(m[1,2:5],nrow=2,ncol=2)` and one for `matrix(m[1,6:9],nrow=2,ncol=2)`. This would represent a huge waste of memory in my concrete case.

I suppose at some point I must read more in detail how R does this kind of memory management, but I'd be grateful for answers and explanations for this specific case for the moment.

**Edit**: from experimenting with `tracemem`, as suggested by jay.sf in the comments, it looks like a slice might actually be copied **twice**! Once to create the input to `dnorm`, and once because `dnorm` seems to internally copy the `mean` argument...

Comment: You might find `?tracemem` helpful.

Comment: Thank you @jay.sf! I'll check that immediately.

Comment: @jay.sf from what I'm seeing using `tracemem`, the very use of `dnorm` copies whatever its used as `mean` and `sd` arguments. In this case, the `matrix` operation becomes unimportant...

Comment: You are right in assuming that slices and subsets are duplicated. I once participated in an R Users group where Max Kuhn showed how a simple replacement of values in a data frame can make as many as 4 copies of parts or whole data frames. I do not imagine that a slice is any different given how R processes object.

My solution would be to create a variable which is an array of dimensions to feed into your processing function and then use a loop with garbage collection and clearing at the end of each loop. This way you will remove the kruft created in the function and the `dnorm()`)

Comment: @sconfluentus thank you for the info and suggestion – please feel free to post it as an answer :)